# Issue Compiling Qt 5.5 for Windows Phone 8.1 with OpenSSL Support

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, windows-phone-8.1, qt5

I'm trying to build Qt 5.5 for Windows Phone 8.1.
Currently I work on an App using the Qt5 Framework. The App runs fine on iOS and Android. Now I want to support Windows Phone too.

In the App I'm using the OpenSSL API to create a certificate signing request and the corresponding keypair. I also use a QSslSocket. So I need to compile Qt with OpenSSL support.

In my Environment I use:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
- Strawberry Perl (needed to compile OpenSSL)
- Qt Community Edition (online installer)

For Windows Phone I compiled OpenSSL from Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl commit 632474b204aa5fd305e30ca851f1a8c09563dbc3)

To compile OpenSSL I used the Command Shell and executed the following commands (from https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl/blob/WinRT/INSTALL.WINAPP):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
cd C:\openssl
perl Configure no-asm no-hw no-dso VC-WINSTORE
ms\do_winstore
ms\setVSvars ws8.1arm

set LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;%LIBPATH%

nmake -f ms\nt.mak init
nmake -f ms\nt.mak
```

The Compilation seems to be fine.

Then I copied the resulting files from C:\openssl\out32 to C:\lib\openssl

I copied the files from C:\openssl\include to C:\include

For compiling the Qt Framework I use the "VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" as mentioned in http://wiki.qt.io/WinRTBuild

Then in C:\Qt\5.5\Src I execute the two following commands:

```
configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -openssl -I C:\include -L C:\lib\openssl -opensource -prefix C:\Qt\5.5.1 -confirm-license -xplatform winphone-arm-msvc2013 -release

nmake
```

It compiles and after a while it exits with the following errors:

```
...
Generating Code...
        cl -c -FIqt_pch.h -Yuqt_pch.h -Fp.pch\release\Qt5Network_pch.pch -nologo -FS -O2 -MD -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQ_BYTE_ORDER=Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP -DARM -D__ARM__ -D__ARM__ -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_LOCALSOCKET_TCP -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -IC:\include -I..\..\include -I..\..\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\include\QtNetwork\5.5.1 -I..\..\include\QtNetwork\5.5.1\QtNetwork -Itmp -I..\3rdparty\zlib -Ikernel -I..\..\include\QtCore\5.5.1 -I..\..\include\QtCore\5.5.1\QtCore -I..\..\include\QtCore -I.moc\release -I..\..\mkspecs\winphone-arm-msvc2013 -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\gordon\AppData\Local\Temp\nm609E.tmp
qasn1element.cpp
qssl.cpp
qsslcertificate.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_winrt_p.h(68) : error C2011: 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate' : 'class' type redefinition
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate.cpp(572) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate.cpp(592) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
qsslconfiguration.cpp
qsslcipher.cpp
qsslellipticcurve.cpp
qsslkey_p.cpp
qsslerror.cpp
qsslsocket.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_winrt_p.h(68) : error C2011: 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate' : 'class' type redefinition
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
ssl\qsslsocket.cpp(347) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
ssl\qsslsocket.cpp(347) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
qsslpresharedkeyauthenticator.cpp
qsslcertificateextension.cpp
qsslcertificate_qt.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(86) : error C3861: 'q_X509_free': identifier not found
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(54) : error C2039: 'derData' : is not a member of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(76) : error C2039: 'subjectMatchesIssuer' : is not a member of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(121) : error C2039: 'subjectAlternativeNames' : is not a member of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
...
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(377) : error C2660: 'QDataStream::readRawData' : function does not take 1 arguments
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(386) : error C3861: 'parseExtension': identifier not found
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(388) : error C2065: 'extensions' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(398) : error C2065: 'subjectAlternativeNames' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(398) : error C2228: left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(400) : error C2065: 'subjectAlternativeNames' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(400) : error C2228: left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(410) : error C2065: 'derData' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(411) : error C2065: 'null' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(415) : error C2039: 'parseExtension' : is not a member of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(505) : error C2248: 'QSslCertificateExtension::d' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSslCertificateExtension'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(69) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension::d'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(50) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(506) : error C2248: 'QSslCertificateExtension::d' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSslCertificateExtension'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(69) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension::d'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(50) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(507) : error C2248: 'QSslCertificateExtension::d' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSslCertificateExtension'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(69) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension::d'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(50) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(508) : error C2248: 'QSslCertificateExtension::d' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSslCertificateExtension'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(69) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension::d'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(50) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension'
ssl\qsslcertificate_qt.cpp(509) : error C2248: 'QSslCertificateExtension::d' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSslCertificateExtension'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(69) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension::d'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificateextension.h(50) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificateExtension'
qsslcertificate_winrt.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(86) : error C3861: 'q_X509_free': identifier not found
ssl\qsslcertificate_winrt.cpp(98) : error C2039: 'derData' : is not a member of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate_winrt.cpp(98) : error C2228: left of '.length' must have class/struct/union
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(74) : see declaration of 'QSslCertificatePrivate'
ssl\qsslcertificate_winrt.cpp(98) : error C2228: left of '.data' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslcertificate_winrt.cpp(98) : error C2660: 'ABI::Windows::Security::Cryptography::ICryptographicBufferStatics::CreateFromByteArray' : function does not take 2 arguments
qsslkey_qt.cpp
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(117) : error C2039: 'Cipher' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(117) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(117) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(117) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(118) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(118) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(146) : error C2065: 'derData' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(146) : error C2228: left of '.clear' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(147) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(179) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(189) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(195) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(213) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(219) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(232) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(236) : error C2065: 'derData' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(252) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(252) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(252) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(254) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(254) : error C2065: 'DesCbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(256) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(256) : error C2065: 'DesEde3Cbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(258) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(258) : error C2065: 'Rc2Cbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(265) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(266) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(266) : error C3861: 'decrypt': identifier not found
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(273) : error C2065: 'keyLength' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(288) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(288) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(288) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(288) : error C2065: 'DesEde3Cbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(289) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(290) : error C2065: 'cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(290) : error C2065: 'derData' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(290) : error C3861: 'encrypt': identifier not found
ssl\qsslkey_qt.cpp(295) : error C2065: 'derData' : undeclared identifier
qsslkey_winrt.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(86) : error C3861: 'q_X509_free': identifier not found
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(87) : error C2039: 'Cipher' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(87) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(87) : error C2923: 'QHash' : 'Cipher' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Key'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(60) : error C2512: 'QHash' : no appropriate default constructor available
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(72) : error C2039: 'DesCbc' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(72) : error C2065: 'DesCbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(72) : error C2660: 'ABI::Windows::Security::Cryptography::Core::ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProviderStatics::OpenAlgorithm' : function does not take 1 arguments
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(75) : error C2039: 'DesEde3Cbc' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(75) : error C2065: 'DesEde3Cbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(75) : error C2660: 'ABI::Windows::Security::Cryptography::Core::ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProviderStatics::OpenAlgorithm' : function does not take 1 arguments
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(78) : error C2039: 'Rc2Cbc' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(78) : error C2065: 'Rc2Cbc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(78) : error C2660: 'ABI::Windows::Security::Cryptography::Core::ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProviderStatics::OpenAlgorithm' : function does not take 1 arguments
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(92) : error C2039: 'Cipher' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(92) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(92) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(92) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(93) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(93) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(146) : error C2039: 'decrypt' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(146) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(146) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(146) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(147) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(147) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(151) : error C2039: 'encrypt' : is not a member of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslkey_p.h(61) : see declaration of 'QSslKeyPrivate'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(151) : error C2065: 'Cipher' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(151) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'cipher'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(151) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(152) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
ssl\qsslkey_winrt.cpp(152) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
qsslsocket_winrt.cpp
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslcertificate_p.h(86) : error C3861: 'q_X509_free': identifier not found
qsslellipticcurve_dummy.cpp
qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp
qsslcontext_openssl.cpp
ssl\qsslcontext_openssl.cpp(471) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'ssl_session_st'
        C:\include\openssl/ssl.h(352) : see declaration of 'ssl_session_st'
ssl\qsslcontext_openssl.cpp(471) : error C2227: left of '->tlsext_tick_lifetime_hint' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
qsslellipticcurve_openssl.cpp
Generating Code...
Compiling...
qsslkey_openssl.cpp
qsslsocket_openssl.cpp
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(87) : error C2039: 'ptrCertOpenSystemStoreW' : is not a member of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_p.h(97) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(87) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ptrCertOpenSystemStoreW'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(87) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(88) : error C2039: 'ptrCertFindCertificateInStore' : is not a member of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_p.h(97) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(88) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ptrCertFindCertificateInStore'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(88) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(89) : error C2039: 'ptrCertCloseStore' : is not a member of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_p.h(97) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketPrivate'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(89) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ptrCertCloseStore'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(89) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(549) : error C3861: 'LoadLibraryW': identifier not found
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(556) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(557) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(558) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(749) : error C2065: 'HCERTSTORE' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(749) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hSystemStore'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(749) : error C2065: 'hSystemStore' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(757) : error C2065: 'hSystemStore' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(757) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(759) : error C2065: 'hSystemStore' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(760) : error C2065: 'PCCERT_CONTEXT' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(760) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pc'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(760) : error C2065: 'pc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(762) : error C2065: 'pc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(762) : error C2065: 'hSystemStore' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(762) : error C2065: 'X509_ASN_ENCODING' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(762) : error C2065: 'CERT_FIND_ANY' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(763) : error C2065: 'pc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(765) : error C2065: 'pc' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(765) : error C2227: left of '->pbCertEncoded' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(765) : error C2227: left of '->cbCertEncoded' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(769) : error C2065: 'hSystemStore' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1430) : error C2065: 'PCCERT_CONTEXT' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1430) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wincert'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1430) : error C2065: 'wincert' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1430) : error C2065: 'X509_ASN_ENCODING' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1430) : error C3861: 'CertCreateCertificateContext': identifier not found
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1431) : error C2065: 'wincert' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1440) : error C2065: 'CERT_CHAIN_PARA' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1440) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'parameters'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1440) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1441) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1441) : error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1442) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1442) : error C2228: left of '.cbSize' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1442) : error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1444) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1444) : error C2228: left of '.RequestedUsage' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1444) : error C2228: left of '.dwType' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1444) : error C2065: 'USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1445) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1445) : error C2228: left of '.RequestedUsage' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1445) : error C2228: left of '.Usage' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1445) : error C2228: left of '.cUsageIdentifier' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1446) : error C2065: 'szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1446) : error C2065: 'szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1447) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1447) : error C2228: left of '.RequestedUsage' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1447) : error C2228: left of '.Usage' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1447) : error C2228: left of '.rgpszUsageIdentifier' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1453) : error C2065: 'PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1453) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'chain'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1453) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1456) : error C2065: 'wincert' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1459) : error C2065: 'parameters' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1462) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1454) : error C3861: 'CertGetCertificateChain': identifier not found
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1494) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1494) : error C2227: left of '->TrustStatus' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1494) : error C2228: left of '.dwErrorStatus' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1495) : error C2065: 'CERT_TRUST_NO_ERROR' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1495) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1495) : error C2227: left of '->cChain' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'finalChain'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C2065: 'finalChain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C2227: left of '->rgpChain' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1496) : error C2227: left of '->cChain' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1499) : error C2065: 'finalChain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1499) : error C2227: left of '->TrustStatus' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1499) : error C2228: left of '.dwErrorStatus' must have class/struct/union
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1500) : error C2065: 'CERT_TRUST_NO_ERROR' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1500) : error C2065: 'finalChain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1500) : error C2227: left of '->cElement' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1501) : error C2065: 'finalChain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1501) : error C2227: left of '->rgpElement' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1501) : error C2227: left of '->cElement' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1501) : error C2227: left of '->pCertContext' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2227: left of '->pbCertEncoded' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2065: 'finalChain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2227: left of '->rgpElement' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2227: left of '->cElement' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is 'unknown-type'
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2227: left of '->pCertContext' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1502) : error C2227: left of '->cbCertEncoded' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1505) : error C2065: 'chain' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1505) : error C3861: 'CertFreeCertificateChain': identifier not found
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1507) : error C2065: 'wincert' : undeclared identifier
ssl\qsslsocket_openssl.cpp(1507) : error C3861: 'CertFreeCertificateContext': identifier not found
qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_arm\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

It seems to me that there is something wrong with the OpenSSl library.
Does anyone have a clue what I can do to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used OpenSSL with Qt5.5 in iOS (I started back a few versions ago, and have successfully moved forward with it.)  I haven't tried in Windows, but I'll probably need to at some point, so your post worries me!

Anyway, I've used a number of libraries which had similar problems to begin with.  It looks like you have a bunch of duplicate code now which is colliding.  You need to exclude parts of the source.

Focus on one of these at a time.  I suggest starting with your first error:

```
c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_winrt_p.h(68) : error C2011: 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate' : 'class' type redefinition
        c:\qt\5.5\src\qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_p.h(100) : see declaration of 'QSslSocketBackendPrivate'
```

Apparently, by the time you get to qsslsocket_winrt_p.h, you've already defined the QSslSocket class.  Look through the list of files which compiled before that.  It ought to be in there if you open them or search through with your IDE.  Try "removing" the offending blocks of code from either the first or second attempts to define the class by adding precomplier directives around it, ie. #define, #ifdef, etc.

It might take a day's work, but you ought to be able to sift though it eventually... I've been there!

Comment: I think you are right. Since Qt 5.6 is out now, I will just give that a try.